# import or require not working on aws lamda

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function on aws. I want to send user data after they signup to my mongodb database. I triggered the lambda function using "pre authenticate" method. however, "I am getting this error " preauthentication failed with error cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs. "

my lambda function code:

```
import AWS  from 'aws-sdk'
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

exports.handler = async (event) => {
 try{
     // Retrieve the user data from the event object
  const userData = event.request.userAttributes;

  // Connect to the MongoDB database
  const client = await MongoClient.connect("database url", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  const db = client.db("Cluster0");
  const collection = db.collection("users");

  // Insert the user data into the collection
  await collection.insertOne(userData);

  // Close the database connection
  client.close();
 }catch(error){
    callback(error, event)
 }
};
```

my question is do I have to install mongodb and aws sdk on lambda function folder?
I am writing lambda function from aws website.

Comment: You need to package your dependencies alongside your own code, yes. `aws-sdk` should be installed though if you use the default runtime, that is (one of) the only ones you do not need to package yourself.

Comment: hi. I choose node js.
my process: 
1. I went to lamda page
2. created a fucntion and choose node js
3. then I wrote my code
4. I triggered the code from aws cognito.

right now, I don't have a package.json file there.
I did not understand your answer. can you tell me again what I have to do.

Answer (score 5):

> cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs

This error is usually caused by using the SDK V2 import statements while using a Lambda runtime which uses SDK V3.

I am guessing you are using the new node runtime 18 on Lambda. This runtime uses the Node SDK V3 which supports modular imports like so:

`const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");`

You can either change to a lower runtime or change your code to suit the Node V3 SDK imports:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/#modularized-packages

I also don't believe Lambda runtimes have the MongoDB client built in, which means you will need to create the package locally or use a [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/serverless-development-lambda-atlas/

If you are not tied down to MongoDB, you can use DynamoDB which has a built in client for the Lambda runtime.

Comment: I try to use aws layer. here is what I have done
1. locally installed MongoDB and aws sdk
2. move modules and package.js files to nodejs folder
3. uploaded the folder on aws layer
4. connected the layer.

I am getting this error " Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: You need to see the `type` attribute to `module` in your package.json file: `{
  "type": "module",
  // rest ...
}`